# Window.Show() doesn't display controls but Window.ShowDialog() does

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

I'm trying to create a new `Window` on a button click, but when I display it using `Window.Show()` only the Window frame itself is shown (not the content).  When I do the same thing, but display it using `Window.ShowDialog()`, the controls are shown.

The following code shows the creating and displaying of the dialog using `Window.Show()`:

```
//in MainWindow.xaml.cs
ProgressBox prg = new ProgressBox("wErg", "Connecting to device...");
prg.Show();
; //do stuff 
prg.Close();
```

This produces:
[image: Window.Show dialog created]

While the following code...

```
//in MainWindow.xaml.cs
ProgressBox prg = new ProgressBox("wErg", "Connecting to device...");
prg.ShowDialog();
;//do stuff
prg.Close();
```

Produces:
[image: Window.ShowDialog dialog created]

**Window Code:**

ProgressBox.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="wErg.ProgressBox"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="" Height="106" Width="300" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Status" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar" Height="20"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Percentage" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ProgressBox.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ProgressBox.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ProgressBox : Window
    {

        /*
         * <summary>
         * Constructs a progress bar with a title, text, lower bound (min value), 
         * upper bound (max value), and starting position.
         * </summary>
         */
        public ProgressBox(
            String Title,
            String Status,
            int min,
            int max,
            int pos)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Title = Title;
            this.Status.Text = Status;
            this.ProgressBar.Minimum = min;
            this.ProgressBar.Maximum = max;
            this.ProgressBar.Value = pos;
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public ProgressBox(
            String Title,
            String Status)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Title = Title;
            this.Status.Text = Status;
            this.ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
        }

        /*
         * <summary>
         * Sets the text of the progress dialog
         * </summary>
         */
        public void SetStatus(String Status)
        {
            this.Status.Text = Status;            
        }

        /*
         * <summary>
         * Sets the position of the progress on the bar.
         * and updates the percent string.
         * </summary>
         */
        public bool SetPosition(int pos)
        {
            bool outcome = false;
            if(ProgressBar.Minimum <= pos && pos <= ProgressBar.Maximum)
            {
                this.ProgressBar.Value = pos;
                int percentage = Convert.ToInt32((pos - ProgressBar.Minimum) * 100 / (ProgressBar.Maximum - ProgressBar.Minimum));
                Percentage.Text = percentage.ToString() + "%";
                outcome = true;
            }
            return outcome;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Does it have anything to do with your `// do stuff` because `ShowDialog` blocks the thread it's running until the window is closed, whereas for `Show` you continue and might finish some task really fast (which would otherwise not run for `ShowDialog`) changing the way you're displaying things.

Comment: If you `Connect to a device` in your `do stuff` you are probably blocking the UI thread. I think you have to take a look to the way how you are connecting.

Comment: @Sjips @Vlad I set a break point right on the `Show` and `ShowDialog` and thats when I took the screenshots, so it hadn't executed the "stuff" im doing yet. I actually had the stuff commented out at one point too

Comment: @mdw7326 If you are using `Show` the screen won't be fully rendered until the function that contains `prg.Show();` returns to the message pump (Most likely returning from the click event handler that called the function you are currently in).

Comment: What is the purpose of prg.Show();
; //do stuff 
prg.Close(); ?  It is going to Close()

Comment: I added your code in a quick-and-dirty WPF project, and the progressbar and text showed up normally, both when using `Show()` and `ShowModal()`. Seems that something is going on in your code. If you after `prg.Show();` add `return`, before the `//do stuff` and `prg.Close();`, what happens then? (No breakpoints).

Comment: @Sjips The dialog was displayed after adding the return

Comment: @Blam Not if it is actually doing stuff inbetween.  For testing purposes, I've been just setting a breakpoint inbetween to see the dialog is being created properly

Comment: That is not how it works.  Show and Close are on the main thread and they will be run before the UI is rendered unless your do stuff is blocking.  Not sure what you are tying to do but pretty sure this is not the way to do it.  ShowDialog is different as it is blocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Main window Thread is still working if you open using .show() . 
But if you open progress bar window using ShowDialog() then main thread stop working and start working on progress bar thread.

Use background worker to perform //do stuff.

Try using below code :

```html
            BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            ProgressBox prg = new ProgressBox("wErg", "Connecting to device...");
            bw.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
            {
                //do stuff
            };
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
            {
                prg.Close();
            };
            prg.Show();
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm trying to wait until the process has completed though, Using a background worker will just do the process in the background won't it?

Comment: Ok, I got it to work.. a little. I'm currently restructuring my code to better suit the asychronous worker. Will post response when done.