# Window.Show() doesn't display controls but Window.ShowDialog() does 2

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

I have done like this [Window.Show() doesn't display controls but Window.ShowDialog() does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134254/window-show-doesnt-display-controls-but-window-showdialog-does) to resolve problem. But nonetheless I have the same state of problem. How can I modify below code to resolve this?

```
            TimeWindow aTimeWindow = new TimeWindow();
            BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.DoWork += ((o, ea) => { 
                // Highly time consumable task
                _resetEvent.Set();
            });
            aTimeWindow.Show();
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            _resetEvent.WaitOne();
            aTimeWindow.Close();
```

`_resetEvent` is a field of class. `TimeWindow` just an image with `TextBox` WPF control.

Comment: You are still blocking, instead of using the reset event, just close the time window from the `DoWork` delegate when the work is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just async/await so that the Window is shown and closed when work is complete. Something like:

```
private async void ShowWindow()
{
    var aTimeWindow = new TimeWindow();
    aTimeWindow.Show();
    await Task.Run((Action)DoWork);
    aTimeWindow.Close();    
}

private void DoWork()
{
    // perform long running work here
}
```

Edit:

Not using async/await

```
private void ShowWindow()
{
    var aTimeWindow = new TimeWindow();
    aTimeWindow.Show();

    Task.Run(()=>
    {
        DoWork();
    })
    .ContinueWith((t) =>
    {       
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => 
        {
            aTimeWindow.Close();    
        }));
    });
}

private void DoWork()
{
    // perform long running work here
}
```

Comment: It is considered a "bad practice" to wrap a Task.Run for a whole method, a better approach is in ShowWindow do `await Task.Run(DoWork);` then just have DoWork be `private void DoWork()`. Also, `async void` should only be done to support EventHandlers, `ShowWindow` should really be returning a `Task`. (The -1 was for the `async void`, fix that and I will remove it. Fix the DoWork too and it might even become a +1)

Comment: I've never heard of that being bad practice. Mind explaining why? You've piqued my interest. =]

Comment: Basically you are making a asynchronous wrapper for synchronous method, so I recommend the MSDN article "[Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)". The basic summary: No, let the caller wrap the function call in a `Task.Run`, or even better expose truly asynchronous versions too of your methods...

Comment: Now because DoWork is private it does not really matter, but I bet the OP is new to async programming and it is better to show new programmers good practices even in the areas where those pracices don't matter as much because they often don't know the reasons behind them and don't know when it is ok to not use the "good patterns"

Comment: Thanks for replies, guys. So this decision is for C# 5. But I have just 4 version. Is there some another approach to do async behaviour? PS. I used a  Thread.Run/Join  , but this gives me the same behaviour as using BW.